# Install alternate version of python2.7.9 on rhel7.2

Tags: python, rhel7

RHEL7.2 comes with python2.7.5

I want to install an alternate version of 2.7 (2.7.9) but it keeps messing with my preinstalled version (since both are python2.7).

I run:

```
./configure --enable-shared LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/ --prefix=/usr/local/
make && make altinstall
```

the result is always `/usr/bin/python2.7` being changed. Consequently, yum doesn't work anymore...

How do I install an alternate version of python without messing with the preinstalled python2.7 version?

On another issue, this build process that I inherited is using `make -j2 -o2` but I couldn't find any reference to those flags on make. Does make support these flags (j2, o2)? What's their purpose?

**EDIT**

It appears that that wasn't the culprit.
In my build scripts, right after the installation I was using the following command:

```
grep "/usr/local/lib/" /etc/ld.so.conf || (echo "usr/local/lib/" >> /etc/ld.so.conf && /sbin/ldconfig)
```

That wasn't good as it always linked the python to the newly installed one.
Changing the line to the following fixed the problem:

```
grep "/usr/local/lib/" /etc/ld.so.conf || (echo "/usr/lib\n/usr/local/lib/" >> /etc/ld.so.conf && /sbin/ldconfig)
```

Now, `python` runs 2.7.5 and `python2.7` runs 2.7.9

Regarding the flags on make, I still don't know what they do...

Comment: try to add `&&` before make , `&& make && make install`

Comment: Thanks @garg10may. I found the problem and edited my question accordingly